# Throwing an Error with a Low Severity as a logging method?

Tags: t-sql

I see something new to me, stored procedures that print debug messages by raising errors of low severity:

```
raiserror (@Message, 10 , 1) with  nowait
```

If my stored procedure is initiated with the following  batch command:

```
SQLCMD.EXE -E -S%SqlServer% -d %DatabaseName% -b -Q "dbo.usp_Myproc" >> "%LogFile%"
```

I am presuming that these "error messages" are logged to the file %LogFile%

Is this the case? Would T-SQL PRINT statement do the same, I presume not.

Is this a reasonable approach/what is a better way to log?

Comment: The advantage of using `with  nowait` is so that the output gets sent straight away instead of waiting for the buffer to fill up so useful for tracking long running progress. This gets sent as an informational message rather than an error message so assume will be treated same as print.  Can't you test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

low severity raiserror messages are written to the log file but then again, so are PRINT messages. Therefore, I question why anyone would choose to raise a low severity error message to write informational messages that are not really errors. My suspicion is that they were not aware of the PRINT command, didn't think to use it or didn't care as long as it served their purpose.

Comment: Try both raiserror and print in management studio.  Print can be delayed before you see the output whereas raiserror appears straight away.